# JPA bidirectional relation, JoinColumn not populated

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, bidirectional

I am trying to build a bidirectional relation. When I am trying to save an entry, the item_id will be null in the Details table, everything else is populated.

inverse side, Item class:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Details.class, mappedBy = "item", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Details> details;
```

owning side, Details class:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Item.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="item_id")
private Item item;
```

What do i miss?

Thanks

Comment: How you are saving show us the code ?

Comment: I just extended CrudRepository for ItemRepository and I simple call the save method.

Comment: yes, it works, thank you